# How enable file-protocol in google chrome frame plugin for IE

Tags: google-chrome-frame, file-uri

I want to open an Html5 page in IE with chrome frame. But only http protocol supported and I can't open a html file from disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in registery path 
HKCU\Software\Google\ChromeFrame
add this key  :  **AllowUnsafeURLs=1** (DWORD)
By adding the **gcf:** prefix to the URL in address bar, the page will load rendered with WebKit/V8
add this key : **IsDefaultRenderer=1** (DWORD)
Makes WebKit/V8 the default rendering technique
sample gcf:c:\test.html