# Google Chrome Frame - Open local links in Windows Explorer

Tags: flash, google-chrome-extension, npapi, google-chrome-frame

I can open local links (file://) in remote sites, which are defined as trusted in registry, from IE using Windows Explorer. That's fine for me.

Now I want to do it in GCF, too. Neither of the following worked. Any ideas?

1.clicking on

```
<a target='_blank' rel='noreferrer' href='file:///C:/'>Open Folder</a>
```

2.clicking on

```
<div target='_blank' rel='noreferrer' onclick='window.open("file:///C:/")'>Open Folder</div>
```

3.Tried to install a .crx extension that uses a NPAPI plugin to access local files using this method: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/external_extensions.html#registry (Extension worked in Chrome but not in GCF)

4.Haven't tried the Flash solution. Is it possible using Flash to open Windows Explorer on specified folder or directly open .doc files with Microsoft Word like IE does when clicking on .doc files.

Thanks.

Comment: For the 3rd method, have you also tried the Registry deployment option? See here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/external_extensions.html#registry It's supposed to load extensions regardless of any user data contexts.

Comment: Yes, I tried the registry method. It didn't work. Are registry keys different for GCF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374500/how-enable-file-protocol-in-google-chrome-frame-plugin-for-ie

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that solution renders file:// url with GCF. i.e. it does not open it in Windows Explorer. Instead it lists local folder as a html page.

Comment: I gave you that link so you can research registry-based GCF policies. I know there are URL & extension whitelist/blacklist policies, there might be policies which allow you to disable GCF for certain URIs, in your case those which match the `file:///` protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not possible right now. I filed a bug
crbug.com/129183